# slideToggle NEXT li element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, slidetoggle

Trying to build a FAQ page using jQuery. This is the js I'm working with:

```
$("#faq li").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).next("#faq li ul").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Not sure why it isn't working, any help is appreciated.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul id="faq">

<li>Where are you located?
<ul>
We are located in Southern Cali!
</ul>
</li>

<li>What are your service times?
<ul>
Our service times are 7:00, 8:00, and 9:00!
</ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Haven't you swapped `ul` and `li` in the selector? Maybe
`$(this).next("#faq ul li").slideToggle("fast");`?

By the way, it would be nice to see your HTML structure.

Comment: That part is right, it's a ul nested within an li element.

Comment: @ftntravis please show your markup, then, and describe the desired result.  Nesting `ul > li > ul > li` can cause problems because your initial selector will match _both_ levels of `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<li>` must always be a child of a `<ul>`, and a `<ul>` can contain nothing else.  That latter point means that your markup is invalid.

You should perhaps use a `<dl>` (definition list) instead and then use `<dt>` for the item titles and `<dd>` for the item text.  That would be the sort of list intended *exactly* for this use case:

```
<dl id="faq">
<dt>Where are you located?</dt>
<dd>We are located in Southern Cali!</dd>
<dt>What are your service times?</dt>
<dd>Our service times are 7:00, 8:00, and 9:00!</dd>
</dl>
```

with code as follows (using event delegation)

```
$("#faq dt").click(function() {
   $(this).next('dd').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that with a "ul" instead with no luck. I posted my HTML above.

Comment: Thanks! I put in an edit with working JS. This works perfect now, and with clean markup!

Answer (score 0):

Note that `ul` you want to expand on click is a child of `li`, not a sibling. So, you should use `.children('ul')` instead of `.next('#faq ul li')`.

Try this:

```
$("#faq li").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).children("ul").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Also, this is not a good practice to put the text inside an `ul`. Consider replacing inner `ul` with `div` or other element.

Comment: It's not just "not a good practice" to put text in a `ul`, it's invalid HTML.